# Which Star Trek bridge officers ultimately ended up as a Captain?

Tags: star-trek

In watching a good chunk of Star Trek episodes, there are several mentions of Enterprise officers ending up commanding a starship (e.g. Worf commanding the Defiant or Crusher commanding a Science Vessel).

Which main characters across the different series ultimately command their own starship?

Comment: Including the Enterprise?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you count temporary [You Are In Command Now](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouAreInCommandNow) situations, the answer is going to be pretty close to "all of them". So I'll ignore those (though I'll include command situations within the show's run that were either official or expected to be permanent). Corrections are welcome (especially for Voyager and Enterprise, which I'm less familiar with).

Original series crew:

- **Kirk** is in command of the *Enterprise* during the show's run.
- **Spock** commands the *Enterprise* in the period right before *Wrath of Khan*, when it's being used as a training ship. He also commands the *Jellyfish* in the reboot (though that's a one-man non-Starfleet ship...)
- **Sulu** commands the *Excelsior* in *The Undiscovered Country* (and that one *Voyager* episode).
- McCoy, Scotty, Chekhov, and Uhura never get assigned their own commands (unless you want to count the Enterprise-D shuttlecraft that Scotty ended up with in "Relics").

TNG crew:

- **Picard** commands the *Enterprise-D*.
- **Riker** takes command of the *Titan* in *Nemesis*.
- **Dr. Crusher** is seen in command of the *Pasteur* in the alternate future shown in "All Good Things..."
- **Data** commands the *Sutherland* during the Romulan blockade in "Redemption".
- **LaForge** commands the *Challenger* in the alternate future shown in the *Voyager* episode "Timeless".
- Troi, Wesley Crusher, and Tasha Yar never seem to be in command of anything.

DS9 crew:

- **Sisko**, **Worf**, **Dax**, and **Kira** all spend time in command of the *Defiant*.
- O'Brien, Bashir, and Odo never seem to command anything (except for temporary stints on runabouts).

Voyager crew:

- **Janeway** commands *Voyager*.
- **Chakotay** ends up in command of *Voyager* in at least one alternate timeline (in "Before and After").
- **Tuvok** is placed in command of *Voyager* in "Resolutions".
- **Harry** commands the Kraylor medical transport *Nightingale* during the episode of the same name, and commands the Starfleet ship *Rhode Island* in the alternate future of the series finale.
- **Neelix** has his own ship (the *Baxial*) at the start of the series.  Voyager keeps it aboard, and it gets used several times during the show's run.
- Paris, B'Elanna, Kes, the Doctor, and Seven of Nine never seem to command anything.

Enterprise crew:

- **Archer** commands the *Enterprise*.
- **T'Pol** takes command of the *Enterprise* in the alternate future shown in "Twilight"...
- ...and then **Trip** succeeds her.
- Also in the "Twilight" future, **Reed** is assigned command of the *Intrepid*, but he gets killed and then the reset button gets pushed before the beginning of his stint.
- The mirror-universe version of **Hoshi** ends up in command of the *Defiant* by the end of "In A Mirror, Darkly".
- Mayweather and Phlox never seem to command anything.

Comment: Just a small point: the Jellyfish was a Vulcan Science vessel, not a Starfleet one

Comment: @Monty129: Duly noted.

Comment: In addition to my edit, Paris also briefly had his own ship (_Alice_), in the episode of the same name (6x05), though I'm not sure if that counts.

Comment: Does the Delta Flyer count?  It is more than a runabout, although still quite small...  (How does it compare to Neelix's ship, which fit in Voyager?)

Comment: @Compro01: I think "One" and "Workforce" are both the kind of temporary situation I was trying to avoid talking about (though longer-term than most).

Comment: (And I think *Alice* is in command of herself...)

Comment: It's also worth noting that Riker was repeatedly offered his own ship long before he took command of the Titan. He could have been captain of the USS Drake in 2364 before he joined the Enterprise-D, then the USS Aries in 2365, then the USS Melbourne in 2366. He was then given a field promotion to captain in December of 2366 and took over the Enterprise-D to rescue Picard. So he could have made captain a full 15 years before he took command of the USS Titan.

Worf was also in command of the IKS Koraga, but only his mirror universe self truly had his own ship.

Comment: T'Pol was in command several times (she was the first officer after all), not sure if any of those situations count though. AFAIK, both Trip and Reed were captains in one of the [alternate futures](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Twilight_(episode)). I'm pretty sure Scotty was a captain (by rank) in The Undiscovered Country, I don't know if he had a command though.

Comment: @muistooshort: Thanks for pointing out "Twilight" to me -- that gets a lot of the Enterprise crew! Scotty and McCoy definitely both held the rank of captain (unless McCoy somehow managed to skip it on his way to becoming an admiral), but I can't find any evidence that they actually captained ships...

Comment: Wasn't there one episode or so in Voyager where the Doctor got some kind of command upgrade and piloted/commanded the Voyager all by himself, because the entire crew was somehow incapacitated? I vaguely remember such an episode. That wouldn't count as a *you're in command* situation, because I think it covered several days or even weeks of time in universe.

Comment: @Sebastian_H: Yes, I remember that, too. I think his uniform even changed to red for that. But I also cannot remember the episode.

Comment: @Sebastian_H: That happens in "Workforce", which I decided was too temporary for my purposes. Yes, it plays out over a long period of time, but the expectation when the Doctor takes command is always that he's going to hand it back to Janeway at the end of the crisis (in contrast to something like "Resolutions", where Janeway and Chakotay expect to spend the rest of their lives on the planet).

Comment: The Doctor is a special case, as holographic entities and AI are not generally considered individuals within the Federation (Data is the only exception I can think of). They have no legal status as citizens and are neither enlisted men nor commissioned officers (they're generally classified as equipment). So the Doctor has no way to progress in rank within Starfleet.

Comment: _"Troi, Wesley Crusher, and Tasha Yar never seem to be in command of anything."_ Thank Jesus.

Answer (score 3):

Non Temporary Duty:

Not counting the captains...
Nor mirror universe

TOS:
Sulu is shown in the movies to captain an Excelsior class.
Spock is captain of record when the Enterprise is a training ship (ST II)

**TNG**:
Riker moves on to the Titan in Nemesis.
Dr. Crusher gets the Pasteur (All Good Things)
LaForge has command of the Challenger in 2290 (Timeless)†

**DS9**:
Colonel Kira takes over DS9 when Captain Sisko "disappears."

**Voyager**:
None. We don't see any future bits for these characters, and all commands are temporary duty, not "permanent party assignments".

---

† Included because the time-loop has to occur in order to exist. It's not an alternate timeline; it's a temporal anomaly.

Comment: It's quite obviously an alternate timeline.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you include the books as well.  Riker commands the Titan.  Crusher, at least in an alternate universe, commands the USS Pasteur.  La Forge is seen to command vessels in Voyager too, which in the episode Timeless (Season 5 Episode 6) was named as the USS Challenger.  I think Ro Laren also commanded DS9 in the Typhon Pact books as well.  Not 100% sure about that one though.